# Asterisk : Meetme application is not found

Tags: asterisk

I am learning asterisk.

I learned about the application meetme which is used to make a conference call.
I am using asterisk 1.6.

In that the application meetme is not found.What shall I need to do to work with meetme application.

Please Help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you build asterisk, before the plain "make" you have to run "make menuconfig" to set what channels, drivers, codecs, applications, functions, etc you want to use. Run that and select the meetme application, which is probably not selected.

Also you will need a meetme.conf file in /etc/asterisk, with the config you want to have for that app.

Answer (score 0):

On newer versions of Asterisk Meetme has been replaced by app_confbridge.  This removes the need for timers and also supports higher quality calls - the conference is no longer downsampled to 8KHz.